# HashSet.remove() and Iterator.remove() not working

Tags: java, collections

I'm having problems with Iterator.remove() called on a HashSet.

I've a Set of time stamped objects.  Before adding a new item to the Set, I loop through the set, identify an old version of that data object and remove it (before adding the new object).  the timestamp is included in hashCode and equals(), but not equalsData().

```
for (Iterator<DataResult> i = allResults.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
{
    DataResult oldData = i.next();
    if (data.equalsData(oldData))
    {   
        i.remove();
        break;
    }
}
allResults.add(data)
```

The odd thing is that i.remove() silently fails (no exception) for some of the items in the set.  I've verified

- The line i.remove() is actually called.  I can call it from the debugger directly at the breakpoint in Eclipse and it still fails to change the state of Set
- DataResult is an immutable object so it can't have changed after being added to the set originally.
- The equals and hashCode() methods use @Override to ensure they are the correct methods.  Unit tests verify these work.
- This also fails if I just use a for statement and Set.remove instead.  (e.g. loop through the items, find the item in the list, then call Set.remove(oldData) after the loop).
- I've tested in JDK 5 and JDK 6.

I thought I must be missing something basic, but after spending some significant time on this my colleague and I are stumped.  Any suggestions for things to check?

EDIT:

There have been questions - is DataResult truly immutable.  Yes.  There are no setters.  And when the Date object is retrieved (which is a mutable object), it is done by creating a copy.

```
public Date getEntryTime()
{
    return DateUtil.copyDate(entryTime);
}

public static Date copyDate(Date date)
{
    return (date == null) ? null : new Date(date.getTime());
}
```

FURTHER EDIT (some time later):
For the record -- DataResult was not immutable!  It referenced an object which had a hashcode which changed when persisted to the database (bad practice, I know).  It turned out that if a DataResult was created with a transient subobject, and the subobject was persisted, the DataResult hashcode was changed.

Very subtle -- I looked at this many times and didn't notice the lack of immutability.

Comment: Two possibilities. 1. You say that DataResult is immutable. Is it safe to assume that values are set by the constructor and there are no set methods? 2. Your equals and hashcode aren't working as you expect. Can you post up the code for those two?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I was very curious about this one still, and wrote the following test:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class HashCodeTest {
    private int hashCode = 0;

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return hashCode ++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<HashCodeTest> set = new HashSet<HashCodeTest>();

        set.add(new HashCodeTest());
        System.out.println(set.size());
        for (Iterator<HashCodeTest> iter = set.iterator();
                iter.hasNext();) {
            iter.next();
            iter.remove();
        }
        System.out.println(set.size());
    }
}
```

which results in:

```
1
1
```

If the hashCode() value of an object has changed since it was added to the HashSet, it seems to render the object unremovable.

I'm not sure if that's the problem you're running into, but it's something to look into if you decide to re-visit this.

Comment: Thanks-- that's much appreciated.  I suspect you might be right.  Will go revisit my unit tests for equals/hashCode on the base object.

Comment: Six years later and this answer has saved me further hours of head-desk interaction. +1. +allthe1s.

Comment: +1; This solution just helped me solve a frustrating bug in building a set of subgraphs.  I would like to add that the reason this occurs appears to be that HashSet wraps HashMap.  The values in the hash are being treated as keys instead of values.  Of course keys cannot be mutable, but it is frustrating that the intuitive notion that sets are composed by iteration is violated...

Comment: "If the hashCode() value of an object has changed since it was added to the HashSet, it seems to render the object unremovable." That's gold.

Comment: Ok, so it's impossible to remove such an element or perhaps should we re-instantiate `set` with `new HashSet<>(set)` everytime this happens?

Comment: @Henri, Honestly, I'd say it's best to make sure this doesn't happen, for instance, by making the contents of your set immutable.

That said, if you can't avoid it, what you are suggesting seems like it would work.

Comment: Thanks so much!. After I changed the hashCode() and equals() methods to remove things that were not really necessary it started working.

Answer (score 7):

Under the covers, HashSet uses HashMap, which calls HashMap.removeEntryForKey(Object) when either HashSet.remove(Object) or Iterator.remove() is called.  This method uses both hashCode() and equals() to validate that it is removing the proper object from the collection.

If both Iterator.remove() and HashSet.remove(Object) are not working, then something is definitely wrong with your equals() or hashCode() methods.  Posting the code for these would be helpful in diagnosis of your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Are you absolutely certain that DataResult is immutable? What is the type of the timestamp? If it's a `java.util.Date` are you making copies of it when you're initializing the DataResult? Keep in mind that `java.util.Date` is mutable.

For instance:

```
Date timestamp = new Date();
DataResult d = new DataResult(timestamp);
System.out.println(d.getTimestamp());
timestamp.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(d.getTimestamp());
```

Would print two different times.

It would also help if you could post some source code.

Comment: @Jack Leow: That's a great comment.  However, I am copying the date object before exposing via the getter.  (Been reading edition 2 of Bloch's Effectiva Java recently).  So DataResult is truly immutable.

Comment: copying the value or the reference ?

Comment: @Blade: creates a new instance of Date.  See edit to original question.

Answer (score 4):

You should all be careful of any Java Collection that fetches its children by hashcode, in the case that its child type's hashcode depends on its mutable state. An example:

```
HashSet<HashSet<?>> or HashSet<AbstaractSet<?>> or HashMap variant:
```

HashSet retrieves an item by its hashCode, but its item type
is a HashSet, and hashSet.hashCode depends on its item's state.

Code for that matter:

```
HashSet<HashSet<String>> coll = new HashSet<HashSet<String>>();
HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
set1.add("1");
coll.add(set1);
print(set1.hashCode()); //---> will output X
set1.add("2");
print(set1.hashCode()); //---> will output Y
coll.remove(set1) // WILL FAIL TO REMOVE (SILENTLY)
```

Reason being is HashSet's remove method uses HashMap and it identifies keys by hashCode, while AbstractSet's hashCode is dynamic and depends upon the mutable properties of itself.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the help.  I suspect the problem must be with equals() and hashCode() as suggested by spencerk.  I did check those in my debugger and with unit tests, but I've got to be missing something.

I ended up doing a workaround-- copying all the items except one to a new Set.  For kicks, I used Apache Commons CollectionUtils.

```
    Set<DataResult> tempResults = new HashSet<DataResult>();
    CollectionUtils.select(allResults, 
            new Predicate()
            {
                public boolean evaluate(Object oldData)
                {
                    return !data.equalsData((DataResult) oldData);
                }
            }
            , tempResults);
    allResults = tempResults;
```

I'm going to stop here-- too much work to simplify down to a simple test case.  But the help is miuch appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost certainly the case the hashcodes don't match for the old and new data that are "equals()". I've run into this kind of thing before and you essentially end up spewing hashcodes for every object and the string representation and trying to figure out why the mismatch is happening.

If you're comparing items pre/post database, sometimes it loses the nanoseconds (depending on your DB column type) which can cause hashcodes to change.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like

```
boolean removed = allResults.remove(oldData)
if (!removed) // COMPLAIN BITTERLY!
```

In other words, remove the object from the Set and break the loop.  That won't cause the `Iterator` to complain.  I don't think this is a long term solution but would probably give you some information about the `hashCode`, `equals` and `equalsData` methods

Comment: I was running in a similar problem as the OP, but the removed flag was always true - even though the actual object was not removed from the HashSet. So, there has to be a different way.

Answer (score 1):

The Java HashSet has an issue in "remove()" method. Check the link below. I switched to TreeSet and it works fine. But I need the O(1) time complexity.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154740

Answer (score -2):

If there are two entries with the same data, only one of them is replaced... have you accounted for that? And just in case, have you tried another collection data structure that doesn't use a hashcode, say a List?

Comment: that's right, but dupes are defined by the equals() method, which in this case uses the data + timestamp.

Answer (score -4):

I'm not up to speed on my Java, but I know that you can't remove an item from a collection when you are iterating over that collection in .NET, although .NET will throw an exception if it catches this.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: While it is sometimes true that you cannot remove an element from a collection backing an iterator (a ConcurrentModificationException could be thrown), you can remove the element directly through the Iterator itself, if it supports the action, which it does for HashSet.

Comment: And the iterators which don't support removal at all throw UnsupportedOperationException on any remove() attempt.