# Why does iterator.remove() on a HashSet of ebean (ORM) model-objects not work?

Tags: java, iterator, playframework-2.0, hashset, ebean

I am using ebean for ORM in my Play 2.3 app. When I iterate through my `HashSet` to remove a matching model object, `iterator.remove()` is not working. To determine which model to remove, I am not even relying on the `modelObject.equals()`-method, instead I am simply comparing a String:

```
public boolean deleteToken(final User user, final String token) {
    if (token == null || token.isEmpty()) return false;

    int previousTokenSetSize = user.tokens.size();
    Iterator<Token> iterator = user.tokens.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      final Token tokenObj = iterator.next();
      if (tokenObj.token.equalsIgnoreCase(token)) { // simple String-comparison
        iterator.remove(); // this line is reached, but no effect!
        userRepository.delete(tokenObj);
        break;
      }
    }

    if (user.tokens.size() != previousTokenSetSize) {
      userRepository.update(user);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Please note: this method **does work** if I unit-test without a database. It does not work if I do the same with "live" models and a test-database in a running fake application. When debugging, I see that nothing was removed after iteration (no difference when I move deletion of the model out of the iteration, or put it before `iterator.remove()`). I really don't get this since I am not passing another object, just a String, and am simply trying to remove the current object of the iterator. I'm also not modifying the Set before `remove()` while iterating, therefore the hash-code shouldn't change (or am I missing something?).

I did implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for my models (see below), even simplified those and excluded super, but it doesn't change anything. I'm running out of ideas and would appreciate any help.

`Token`-model class:

```
@Entity
public class Token extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JsonIgnore
    @Required
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public User user;

    @Column(length = 255, unique = true, nullable = false)
    @MaxLength(255)
    @Required
    public String token;

    public Token(User user, String token) {
        this.user = user;
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Token token = (Token) o;

        if (id != null ? !id.equals(token.id) : token.id != null) return false;
        if (user.id != null ? !user.id.equals(token.user.id) : token.user.id != null) return false;
        if (!token.equals(token.token)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (user.id != null ? user.id.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + token.hashCode();

        return result;
    }
}
```

`User` for reference (simplified):

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    // simplified to stress the relevant parts

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonIgnore
    public final Set<Token> tokens = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        // simplified, irrelevant variables excluded
        if (tokens != null ? !tokens.equals(user.tokens) : user.tkens != null) return false;
        if (id != null ? !id.equals(user.id) : user.id != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // simplified, irrelevant variables excluded
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (tokens != null ? tokens.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I did find this: [HashSet.remove() and Iterator.remove() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254441/hashset-remove-and-iterator-remove-not-working)

So, I guess the objects are changed since they are added to the `HashSet`. Simply because with ebean, I create the `Token`-object, add it to the user's token-set, and then update the user in the DB:

```
public String createToken(final User user) {
    final String newToken = generateToken();
    final Token token = new Token(user, newToken);
    user.tokens.add(token);

    userRepository.update(user);

    return newToken;
}
```

That means the ID of the `Token`-object is `null` at the time of adding, and ebean takes care of the ID afterwards. If this renders the token-object non-removable, how should I approach this? I tried excluding the id from the `Token`'s `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, but that also doesn't change anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fell into the trap of mutable fields in hash-based collections. It narrows down to what I put in my edit: when using an ORM like ebean, the `id`-field is mutable (along with other fields like e.g. dates annotated with `@CreatedTimestamp`). So what have we learned:

> Using mutable fields in hashCode() is a recipe for disaster. And
>   disaster strikes when instances of this class are put in a hash-based
>   collection like HashSet or HashMap (as map keys).

Source: http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2012/03/hashset-java-puzzler/

That means I have to reload those model-objects from the database after saving, because only then the `id`-field was populated at the time they were added to the `HashSet`, and only then they can be removed. An alternative would be to exclude the `id`-fields from the `hashCode()`-method, but since they are unique identifiers I'd be careful with that (I guess it would be fine though if you make sure that other unique fields are included).

Comment: Note that there is a difference between the the way this works in Play and pure Ebean.  Specifically with Ebean the hashCode will not change ... and with the Play Model they decided to change that behaviour.

Comment: Interesting, good to know thanks. So they use a different version for Play? Because I just extend from the normal Ebean `Model`. But knowing what exactly was causing it made me able to work around it.

Comment: Play has it's own Model object (which overrides equals and hashCode methods).  ... so now reading your issue again I think I misunderstood. Looking again I now see you had your own equals/hashCode implementation which was able to change (based on the bean values changing) - yup, you have to be careful there.